# Snowflake email notification integration question

Tags: email, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SF has provided us with an email notification procedure. We have to pass in different values to this procedure to send out the notifications to a group email. I wrote another procedure to pass those values from a sql and execute the email notification procedure. It works with individual emails ids but not the group email id. Notification integration was created with group email as allowed recipients, type=email. Can someone please let me know why group email wouldn't work here?
Thanks

Comment: You need to share more code for us to understand what your problem is

Comment: Thanks for looking. This has to do with group email setup and not the snowflake behavior.